# Indicate the color (bronze/silver/gold) in tag badge notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, notifications, tag-badges

Right now there is no difference in the names of bronze, silver and gold tag badges - they're just named after the respective tags themselves. This not only makes the following notification rather ambiguous, but may also create the impression that there's only *one* tag badge, for the uninitiated:

> You've earned the "php" badge. See your profile.

What if the color is specified so it's clear how far we've made in terms of answer scores for a given badge, like so:

> You've earned the bronze "php" tag badge. See your profile.

> You've earned the silver "php" tag badge. See your profile.

> You've earned the gold "php" tag badge. See your profile.

I'm sure quite a number of users keep track of tag progress themselves anyway, but it'd still be nice for the notification to be clearer on this so it's clearer that there are multiple levels of tag badges to earn. Is this a reasonable idea?

This question is specific to tag badges as non-tag badges are all uniquely named, and thus I think indicating the color for those badges won't be necessary. Alternatively, it would be nice for consistency to do this with any badge that is awarded.

Comment: Kinda sucks to see this question earning me 10 upvotes, 100 rep and a badge, yet receiving so little attention otherwise :(

Comment: Why? That's not bad, on Meta. Usually, answers mean that people disagree with you or at least want to modify what you're proposing. Upvotes without answers and comments indicate "this is a perfect request"! But if it makes you feel better, I'll add an answer....

Comment: @Popular Demand: Exactly. Just feels strange that none of the right people are acting on it and making it happen :)

Comment: @Bolt join the club.. I have couple of such requests already. :) Anyhow, you can start Bounty to draw more attention, who knows maybe even Jeff will be lured by this. ;-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Was considering a bounty too, but I don't know how differently bounties work on meta.

Comment: @Bolt afaik it's exactly the same all over the network.. the main bonus that I learned about only recently is that your question will appear in the Featured tab of the homepage: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured :)

Comment: @Popular so you believe feature requests that got no answers and many upvotes are the ones most likely to get the attention from the right people? that'd be good to know!

Comment: @Cawas, in theory...

Comment: I wish I earned enough to care about this.  Not only would I need to be earning silver and gold badges frequently to care, but I'd also have to have so many that I have *no idea which one is coming next...*

Answer (score 11):

+1 to this. But if it falls through, could we at least have this slightly different message?

> You've earned **a** "php" badge. See your profile.

(emphasis added to highlight the difference between "a" and "the")

Answer (score 8):

It was implemented some indefinite time ago :)

> [image]

Now the badge notification is preceded by a badge icon of appropriate color.

Another example from [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com):

[image]