# Badge notifications should have the same color as the badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, notifications, notification-bar

I would like to suggest an update to Stack Exchange sites regarding the notification that is shown when a user earns a new badge.

Currently, all notifications are shown in the same color, like this:

[image: default notification]

This notification is great, but if you get more than one badge, it can be difficult to differentiate between those and "normal" messages.

I would like to propose this:

For each new badge a user earns, the background color should change based on the badge type. So for a gold badge, the background would be gold, etc...

Here's a quick look on how it would look like:

[image: gold badge notification]

Now, if you earn more than one, it will look like this:

[image: all notification]

I think that this way it becomes much easier to distinguish all newly earned badges.

Comment: i think this is a good idea, i am all about design (I am a graphic artists) and of course the first thing i see is colors on a site. I think can improve the visual aspect of it

Comment: personally I don't like the notification bar at all

Comment: +1, great mockups, I can definitely see the value in this. It's not a big change, but it makes the ugly notification bar a little more user-friendly.

Comment: @NickDandoulakis I agree, maybe we have an option to disable it or enable it in the personal prefs!

Comment: @aki I'd like that :)

Comment: @aki "Stack Exchange doesn't have prefeferences" :P

Comment: @slhck well maybe it's time to implement some, this one can be a great one to start with

Comment: i think it is a great idea, and changing css is not really hard to do

Comment: Related: [Indicate the color (bronze/silver/gold) in tag badge notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65517)

Comment: great feature ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is still achievable with the new (now old) notification system:

[image: Inline badge class notifications]

Perhaps a better version with the same theme:

[image: Outline badge class notifications]

This seems like it would work very nicely with the new top-bar as modelled on Meta, which already has a left hand column for reputation points, why not add in badge colours in the matching space for badges?

[image: New Notification System Mockup]

Comment: "How does laughing gas work?"?! I really should check out that site...

Comment: Oh, this could work. Not a fan of the different color text option though

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is necessary at all. The notifications are inside `div#notify-container` and the style of that element appears to come entirely from CSS. What you're proposing would require creating three new notify containers, each with their own CSS. I really don't think this is worth the effort; this is just the notification that you got a badge. If you forgot what class the badge was, *just look at your profile*. There's a lot more information you'd want to see on your profile anyway, so why not just go there?

Basically, there's a lot more useful [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s I'd like to see implemented. This seems like a waste of a dev's time to me...

Comment: what kind of useful feature-request?

Comment: Considering also that the number of notifications have been reduced, having a different background is now less important.

Comment: Why would you have to create three new containers? That's be a silly way to do it. All you would have to do is dynamically change the css.

Comment: @PeterOlson How do you intend to have three badge indicators as shown in the screen capture without three containers?

Comment: @aki, presumarly he's referring to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests (it's a tab on the front page)