# Make badge awards easier to see in the new top bar?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I'm kinda liking the new achievements feature in the new top bar, but I think it'd be nice if badges were easier to distinguish. Maybe put a bronze/silver/gold lozenge where the rep is for the other rows?

Comment: Note the top scored answer in the linked post, it's exactly what you suggest. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Duplicate of a *question* about a long-departed feature? This makes no sense.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, @Roger. The black color looks awesome, though

Comment: @Gilles it was pretty much brought "back to life" with [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133900/152859).

Comment: Voting to re-open. This is a valid feature request in its own right (I came he to suggest it myself). An edit to an answer on an only tangentially related question is very likely to be lost.