# Could we make acceptances a little more obvious in the new topbar?

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, achievements-dialog

In the old Multi-Collider<sup>TM</sup>, an answer acceptance generated an entry that said something like "your answer on (question title) was accepted".<sup>1</sup>  In the new top-bar achievements drop-down, it shows up as a reputation change that is not distinguished in any way from other reputation changes:

[image: screen shot, complete with freehand circle]

The astute reader will see the "15" and make the connection, but if the astute reader has not yet had his morning caffeine, all bets are off.  (I also wonder whether I'd get a notification if the answer were community wiki, thus generating no reputation.)

Could we change something in either the styling or the wording to make this stand out a tad more?

<sup>1</sup> How quickly the memories fade; I don't now remember if it was in the inbox or notifications list.

Comment: It did not do this in the hover menu. It would be fairly complex to send the extra indication of +15 (especially considering that sometimes you get the accept and an upvote which is +25 - what would it show then?).

Comment: @TravisJ it could color it the way it shows on your profile page (the green block).  If you got upvotes and you got a green block that said +35 (or whatever), that'd still tell you there was an acceptance in there.  But I'm not a designer, which is why I didn't make a specific request. :-)

Comment: @TravisJ [example of what I mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ijGZk.png)

Comment: +15 can also be 3 upvotes on a question.

Comment: @Linuxios true, the current design does require me to remember whether that was my question or my answer to somebody else's question.  (Usually I can tell, even without caffeine, but let's not assume...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Especially with upvotes to older questions and answers, its hard to tell.

Comment: I think it also needs the badge icon in that first row as per [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209974/make-badge-awards-easier-to-see-in-the-new-top-bar).

Comment: +1 I'm personally of the opinion that almost all of the menu items would benefit from a more visual, graphic "message type" indicator.  Upvote may be implies fine with the green "+10", but accept, reply, badge, comment, new answer, indicators would make these lists easier to scan. I'm talking to folks internally about what might make sense.

Comment: @Jaydles I gather it didn't go well two years ago. Any chance to talk with some folks again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yeah, this got semi-perma-punted. I'd still like to see something like this, but it's a *lot* more complex than I'd thought at first.   Mostly cuz one entry can result from 3 upvotes, an accept, and a downvote, say.  So it's not as simple as assigning a rep-type indicator for Upvote, Accept, CastDown, GotDown, EditAccept, etc.  You've also got to either combine them, or set hierarchies, etc.

Comment: @Jaydles what does the reputation display on profiles do (both "recent rep changes" and the day-by-day view on the reputation tab)?  Totally different system, it sounds like?  That's a bummer; I'd been hoping there was some code-sharing between profiles and achievements.

Comment: @Jaydles I see. But judging (for example) by the complexity of the Winterbash and how well you're doing it... this would be piece of hat! ;)

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to use the same UI as on the reputation part of the profile page.  The notifications would look something like this (thanks for the mockup, Shadow Wizard):

[image: mockup]

The green background says "there was an acceptance in here", and if the number is something other than 15 you know there were also other rep changes (presumably votes; I don't remember if bounties roll into this).  People already know what this means from [profile pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijGZk.png), so knowledge would transfer more easily than if we came up with a different, achievements-only, styling.

The achievements panel uses the same color scheme (background, font, green) as the profile page.  Even though the fonts are smaller in the achievements panel, this looks quite legible to me.

Comment: This is how it would look like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2XSiP.png feel free to embed it in your answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard; I've incorporated your mockup.