# Why are these reversed downvotes recorded as undownvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes, reputation-graph, serial-voting

Yesterday, a sudden loss of 6 rep led me to discover that my top 3 meta questions were downvoted:

- [Indicate the color (bronze/silver/gold) in tag badge notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65517/indicate-the-color-bronze-silver-gold-in-tag-badge-notifications)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82437/flag-weight-of-510-0000
- [Let users know that they can flag to get their answers reinstated if deleted by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123806/let-users-know-that-they-can-flag-to-get-their-deleted-answers-reinstated-after)

Now, a sudden gain of 6 rep leads me to believe that the downvotes were reversed... but it looks like they were *undone manually*, rather than *reversed* by the vote fraud script:

[image]

How were yesterday's downvotes undone today? I haven't edited my questions since receiving the downvotes. Shouldn't they have been locked in after only 5 minutes?

Comment: Don't they put you through some sort of moderator training? Shouldn't you have every answer to every question (at least meta related)?

Comment: Perhaps the culprit was nice enough to bump-edit my posts, take their votes out and reverse the edits to destroy the revisions and make it seem as if nothing really happened.

Comment: Shouldn't that be visible in the edits though? And by three different people, really? Seems unlikely.

Comment: @M.Babcock: You can silently remove a revision by manually undoing the edits you made, or by saving the previous revision, within the 5-minute grace period.

Comment: @BoltClock: I just tried this. Rolling back doesn't work. Undoing the edit manually does. Weird.

Comment: @BoltClock - That screams like a bug to me. Imagine a similar situation with svn or cvs... this would not be pretty for their development teams at all.

Comment: @Dennis: That has already been established elsewhere. A rollback is considered another edit. You do have to do it manually.

Comment: @animuson - Is that true of rollbacks of another user's edits as well?

Comment: @M.Babcock: No, this applies only to your own edits. It doesn't matter what post you edit, but the *revision* has to be owned by you for it to work. As far as I can tell, this is a side effect of having a 5-minute grace period of not saving revisions.

Comment: @animuson: So this is by-design?

Comment: Then presumably each user would have had to rollback their edits seemingly simultaneously? Highly unlikely. -- I guess this would be to the point of your edit.

Comment: Hmmm... that seems a far stretch to be what's caused this, though. Possible, I guess... to remove the votes without giving themselves away?

Comment: @M.Babcock: The moderator training is rather intensive, but it's what you might call "trial by fire".

Comment: @TheEstablishment - Again, not being a mod I wouldn't know but certainly there is a knowledgebase to leech? (Probably not though... my company doesn't have on either). BTW do you think @_Cody (minus the _) would work? I always wondered since it is an alias from a different site.

Comment: @M.Babcock: No, Meta is what you get. It's accessible to the entire community. The only thing extra mods can do is ask in the Teacher's Lounge, a chat room only for developers and mods. It's possible you might get a faster answer there than on Meta, but I usually just stick with Meta. (I don't think so, no. Comment `@replies` don't care what your user name is *another* site.)

Comment: As a moderator you are supposed to know about meta. even you don't know then what's the difference  between you and other beginner user

Comment: @Mayank swami: What are you talking about? Your comment makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @BoltClock Apparently this has now been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at it now (or any time, when hovering the timestamp to see the exact time when that still displays things like "5 minutes ago"), makes clear it's the fraud script after all. It runs each night at 3:00 AM:

[image]

Still odd, as [it used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) named "reversed", but then didn't indicate on which post this happened:

[image]

Comment: My deduction from this is that there simply weren't enough reversed votes for them to be collapsed into a single "Serial downvoting reversed" entry. As far as I've seen, concentrated vote fraud reversals still display as "Serial upvoting/downvoting reversed".

Comment: Ah, that might very well be true. (I was about to tell you about [another example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135317/what-do-i-do-if-it-looks-like-i-have-a-stack-overflow-user-that-is-messing-with) that came up today, but now I see it's you who pointed me from that post here. `;-)`)