# Indicate the type/colour of badge awarded in the top bar achievements dropdown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Currently with the achievements dropdown for rep changes you see the site icon, then rep change, then a link, but when earning a badge there is a gap where the rep is for reputation achievements.

I think the empty space (where the mouse cursor is in the pic below) should have the badge icon there, possibly linking to the badge in question.

[image]

Comment: Similar to [my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65517/indicate-the-color-bronze-silver-gold-in-tag-badge-notifications) except mine's way, way old and mine's only applicable to tag badges.

Comment: I've just noticed that [privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) have a small icon based on their type. Perhaps that could be included in the appropriate place for those notifications too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now done, horray! And as an unexpected bonus, they even added the badge description. :)

> [image]