# Can we please have the badge colors in the achievements dialog on mobile theme?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, achievements-dialog

Not long ago, badge colors [were added to relevant items in the achievements dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211078/indicate-the-type-colour-of-badge-awarded-in-the-top-bar-achievements-dropdown).

This works well and really excellent, but I do miss this feature on the mobile theme of the site:

> [image]

Can this please be added?